# How to instantiate an Agent via code in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm having an issue with Anylogic: I'm writing a function where I need to declare a new item of the type of an already existing Agent type.
If I declare it with the code:

`MyAgent name = new MyAgent();`

everything is ok but when I try to execute a function to change the value of an internal value,

`name.func();`

it gives me a `NullPointerException`, because the internal variable of the declared `MyAgent` seems not to exist.
What am I missing?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: What do you have inside func()? Please add screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a population use the add_myAgents() method, but if you don't want to use a defined population you have to do this:

```
MyAgent m=new MyAgent();
m.createAndStart(anyAgent);
m.lognormal(0.1,0.1,5);
```

createAndStart does the magic for you.

anyAgent can be actually any existing agent of your model (for example main), the population will still be created in the default population of your top-level agent, no matter what you put in there.

Comment: Are there any benefits to not having a population? `createAndStart() ` will create the same amount of overhead (I assume) so no memory saving... or is there?

Comment: I think it's just more convenient sometimes since i don't want to have populations all over the place... I don't think there's any chance of memory saving, unless you create many instances and want to initialize only a fraction of them while possible discarding the others

Comment: IMO it becomes dangerous to do things outside the realm of what AnyLogic has as standard functionality... (Trust me on this when you get to multithreading and controlling the UI) So if there is no clear benefit I would not advise on doing this.... It might just cost you down the line... But if you know what you are doing go for it! (That means you Felipe ;-) )

Comment: i mean, it's definitely dangerous to do this.. if you forget to createandstart, terrible things can happen, and it's not obvious to remember it... from that perspective, the add_population method is safer, but I will still use this method in some occasions

Answer (score 0):

Certain functions are not available inside agents that get created programmatically, like the default random number generator and certain other utility functions that get passed to agents.

So if you do this for example it wont work, and you get an NPE (Null Pointer Exception)

[image]

Rather always make use of a population - unless you know you will not be using any of those internal functions.

`MyAgent name = add_myAgents();`

Where `myAgents` is a population.